# using QOpenGLWidget trying to draw from different thread with out overriding paintGL

Tags: multithreading, opengl, qt5

Dear All,

Being a newbie to Qt5. Need your expert suggestion on these below problem.

My Qt GUI loop is running on one thread and I’m trying to draw using OpenGL calls from different thread.

My Main GUI thread does the following

- QApplication(argc, argv)
- Create QOpenGLWidget
- Create the shader program
- Run the event loop.

Worker thread

- Make OpenGL calls to draw (say a triangle)

Note: if i put all in paintGL, it works like a charm :)

I tried creating shareContext and then do **makecurrent** | **draw** | **swapbuffers** from the worker thread. But no luck.

I've even tried doing the draw job in the same thread context as the Qt main GUI loop with shared context, like this

main.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char**argv) {
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MyQOpenGLWidget widget;
widget.show();
createShaderProgram(); //Create vertex/fragment shader program
widget.createTriangle(...);
widget.draw(); // This method has a drawing logic of simple triangle
while(widget.isVisible()) { // some busy loop
    widget.processEvents(); // process pending events
}
return 0;
}
```

MyQOpenGLWidget.h

```
class MyQOpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget {

public:
MyQOpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent=0);
~MyQOpenGLWidget();
void createTriangle(int p_vertexAttr, int p_colorAttr, int p_matrixUniform, GLuint pSurfaceProgram);
void draw();

private:
void initializeGL();
//void paintGL(); // No paintGL implementation I've provided
void resizeGL(int w, int h);
void createShareContext () {
    qDebug() << "MyQOpenGLWidget->QThread::currentThread(): " << QThread::currentThread();

    QOpenGLContext *share = context();
    m_context = new QOpenGLContext();
    if (share->isValid()) {
        m_context->setShareContext(share);
        m_context->setFormat(share->format());

        m_Surface = new QOffscreenSurface();
        m_Surface->setFormat(share->format());
        m_Surface->create();
    }
}
Triangle *m_triangle;
QOpenGLContext *m_context;
QOffscreenSurface *m_Surface;
}
```

MyQOpenGLWidget.cpp

```
MyQOpenGLWidget::draw(){
    if (m_context == NULL) {
        createShareContext();
    }
    if (!m_context->isValid()) {
        m_context->create();
    }

    m_context->makeCurrent(m_Surface);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    bind(); // glUseProgram( mSurfaceProgram );

    QMatrix4x4 matrix;
    matrix.ortho(-2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f);
    matrix.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    setUniformValue(m_matrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix.constData()); // glUniformMatrix4fv(...)

    m_triangle->draw(); // Draw triangle
    release(); // glUseProgram( 0 );

    m_context->swapBuffers(m_Surface);
    glFlush();

    m_context->doneCurrent();
}
```

If you have any sample program or any suggestion on how to do the same, it would be great help.

I'm using Qt5.5.0 on Ubuntu, This is the OpenGL output

GL RENDERER         : Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)

GL VERSION          : 2.1 Mesa 8.0.2

GL MAX TEXTURE SIZE : 4096

Comment: What you are trying to do is quite complicated, and slow, so I'd discourage doing this. But if, for some reason, you really need to or don't care about performance: What I think you are omitting is drawing into a shared texture from the second context. So create a texture shared between the two contexts, then draw on it with the second context, sync, and use the first context to draw this shared texture to the screen (or the widget or w/e it is). As you might imagine, this is quite tedious. I'm not very familiar with Qt unfortunately, so I don't know if you can do it without overriding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HenkDeBoer , Off course performance could be a issue but right now not much of concern,  It seems in Qt4.8 using QGLWidget, it was possible to do the same.